# C Operators and Precedence

Tags: c, operators, operator-precedence, sequence-points, logical-and

I'm using C language, for the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int num1=0;

    int res = ++num1 && num1++;

    printf("%d\t%d\n",num1,res);    
}
```

In the above code I get output as `2  1`. I think the output should be `2  0`.

Please correct me if wrong, to solve this statement, the num1++(0) would be executed first due to highest precedence and then ++num1(2) would be executed and then at last && will be preformed because it has the lowest precedence.

Please comment how is this statement getting executed.

In some of the tutorials I find that postfix ++ and prefix ++ have the same precedence, but if that is true then according to the associativity rule again num1++ should be executed first(right to left) which should again lead to answer as `2  0`.

Comment: The `&&` makes a sequence point. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) *it is guaranteed that all side effects of previous evaluations will have been performed, and no side effects from subsequent evaluations have yet been performed*. The evaluation is from left to right.

Comment: Even ***if*** the second part `num1++` were (as you supposed) evaluated first, that would evaluate to `0` and the short-circuit rule would say that because the whole expression cannot be `true`, the other (first) part does not get evaluated, and so `num1` cannot be `2` as you suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of misconceptions here. First of all, operator precedence states the order of *parsing*, not the order of *execution*. There are two related but different terms, operator precedence and order of evaluation.
See [What is the difference between operator precedence and order of evaluation?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/278172).

Once you understand order of evaluation, the `&&` operator specifically comes with well-defined sequencing, which isn't normally the case for C operators. It guarantees a left-to-right order of evaluation. C17 6.5.14/4:

> Unlike the bitwise | operator, the || operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; if the
> second operand is evaluated, there is a sequence point between the evaluations of the first
> and second operands. If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second operand is
> not evaluated.

Normally, you wouldn't be able to wild and crazy things with the ++ operator mixed with other operators, but the above && rule makes it possible in this specific case.

See [Why can't we mix increment operators like i++ with other operators?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/278384) It explains sequencing/sequence points.

---

> In some of the tutorials I find that postfix ++ and prefix ++ have the same precedence,

They don't, prefix ++ takes precedence over postfix (and other unary operators). So associativity does not apply.

Answer (score 3):

In the expression used as an initializer

```
 int res = ++num1 && num1++;
```

there is a sequence point for the operator `&&`.

From the C Standard (6.5.13 Logical AND operator)

> 3 The && operator shall yield 1 if both of its operands compare
> unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type int.

and

> 4 Unlike the bitwise binary & operator, the && operator guarantees
> left-to-right evaluation; if the second operand is evaluated, there is
> a sequence point between the evaluations of the first and second
> operands. If the first operand compares equal to 0, the second operand
> is not evaluated.

At first the left operand of the operator is evaluated and as a result `num1` will be equal to 1 due to the unary (prefix) increment operator. As the sub-expression is not equal to 0 then the second operand is evaluated. Its value is the value before incrementing that is 1. As this second operand is also unequal to 0 then the whole expression is evaluated to the logical true and its value is 1 (see the first quote from the C Standard).

This value 1 is assigned to the variable `res` while the variable `num1` after the postfix increment will be equal to 2.

So you will have that after this declaration `res` is equal to `1` and `num1` is equal to `2`.

Answer (score 0):

> Please correct me if wrong, to solve this statement, the num1++(0) would be executed first due to highest precedence and then ++num1(2) would be executed and then at last && will be preformed because it has the lowest precedence.

Precedence only controls which operators are grouped with which operands - it does not affect the order in which expressions are evaluated.

The `&&`, `||`, `?:`, and comma operator all force left-to-right evaluation - the left operand is fully evaluated (and any side effects applied) before the right operand.  `&&` and `||` both *short circuit* - for `&&`, the right operand will be evaluated only if the left operand is non-zero.

The unary (prefix) `++` operator yields the current value of the operand plus 1, so the result of `++num1` is `1`.  As a *side effect* the value in `num1` is incremented.  Since this result is non-zero, `num1++` is also evaluated.  The postfix `++` operator yields the current value of the operand, so the result of `num1++` is `1`.  As a side effect the value in `num1` is incremented.

The result of an `&&` expression is `1` if both operands are non-zero, `0` otherwise.

It's *roughly* equivalent to writing

```
tmp = num1 + 1;
num1 = num1 + 1;

res = 0;
if ( tmp != 0 )
{
  if ( num1 != 0 )
  {
    res = 1;
  }
}
num1 = num1 + 1;
```

So the *result* of `++num1 && num1++` is `1`, and the value stored in `num1` at the end of it is `2`.

> In some of the tutorials I find that postfix ++ and prefix ++ have the same precedence,

That is *very* wrong and you should stop using those tutorials immediately.  Postfix operators have higher precedence than unary operators - `*a++` is parsed as `*(a++)`, `++a[i]` is parsed as `++(a[i])`, etc.  An expression like `++i++` would be parsed as `++(i++)`, but you can't write such an expression in C - the result of `i++` isn't an *lvalue* and cannot be the operand of a unary `++` like that.